# Pythonで共用されるモジュールの一部の関数だけ実行時に差し替えたい

Tags: python

**環境**  
Windows10 Pro 64bit
Python 3.6.1

下記のモジュール構成だったとします。

```
main.py
A/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

A.a.func()はA.bでも使用されていますが、バグがあり修正する必要があります。ただし、モジュールA内のソースコード(A.a.py, A.b.py)はできれば編集したくありません。

そのため、main.py内で、A.bが使用するA.a.funcだけを差し替えたいのです。
しかし、main.py内で下記のように置き換えても、main.py内では置き換わりますが、A.b内で使用されるA.a.func()は置き換えることができませんでした。

```
# main.py
import A.a

def custom_func():
    return 0

setattr(A.a 'func', custom_func)

# A/b.py
from .a import func

func()      # <= 置き換わっていない
```

何か方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setattr` を使うことで差し替えることが可能でしたよ。
推測としては `setattr(A.a 'func', custom_func)` の実行よりも前に、 `A.b` をうっかりimportしてしまっているコードがあるのでは? という印象です。

main.py

```
import A.a


A.a.f()  # => 'a!'が出力


def custom_func():
    print('custom!!')


setattr(A.a, 'f', custom_func)

from A.a import f

f()  # => 'custom!'が出力

import A.b  # => 'custom!'が出力
```

A/a.py

```
def f():
    print('a!')
```

A/b.py

```
from .a import f


f()
```

Comment: 確かに差し替えできました。差し替え前のシンボル自体を上書きするわけではないので、__init__.pyで当該シンボルがimportされてしまっていた場合はそちらも差し替えないといけないということがわかりました。複雑なライブラリを部分的に差し替えるのは案外面倒ですね(^^;)